# CAShapeLayer won't appear

Tags: swift, uiview

I can't for the life of me figure out why my CAShapeLayer is not appearing in my view. Here is my code:

```
let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    setUpUI()
}

func setUpUI() {
                
    let center = circleTimerView.center
    let radius = circleTimerView.bounds.height / 2
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: -(3/2)*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    circleLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    circleLayer.frame = circleTimerView.frame
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 4
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0

    circleTimerView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
}
```

The circleTimerView appears on my screen, but there is no sign of the layer at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Because strokeEnd is zero?

Comment: As an aside, you should set the `path` for this layer in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (or, better, in the `layoutSubviews` of `circleTimerView`), not in `viewDidLoad`. Constraints have not yet been applied in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @matt my initial reaction was duh, but I removed the strokeEnd line and it didn't change anything. Also tried setting strokeEnd to 1 instead, to no avail.

Comment: Just figured this out, the endAngle of my CGPath was less than my start angle, so it wasn't being drawn. I changed the endAngle to (5/2)*CGFloat.pi and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Cool! You should either answer your own question (totally legal) or delete it. Thanks.

Comment: However I am very surprised if your fixed worked without _also_ fixing the strokeEnd...?

Comment: I did also have to fix the strokeEnd problem, didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out, the endAngle of my CGPath was less than my start angle, so it wasn't being drawn. I changed the endAngle to (5/2)*CGFloat.pi and it worked perfectly. Matt was also right that strokeEnd can't be set to zero, I had that because I was going to animate the strokeEnd paramenter.